# Android application crashing upon connecting to EDGE network

Tags: android, cellular-network

I have developed an Android application that uses a TCP socket connection that listens on and writes to a particular port. My issue is, every time data connection switches to an EDGE connection, the application force closes. I have try catch blocks, none of which throw an exception. Is there a reason why this should happen?

Note: it works fine on other connection types such as HSDPA.

Comment: Can you get any sort of stack trace from it when it dies? Honestly it sounds suspiciously like an OS-level bug...

Comment: No not yet. I am still trying to figure out how to do that. If you happen to know how to do that please let me know?  If not will get back to you after getting these logs.